# Pivot Table Sum Items, But Average Grand Total

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a Standard Pivot Table it has Date from the Columns and Numbers in the Value,

Column: Date | Numbers

I want the Numbers in the Rows to be Calculated as Sum, but I want the Grand Total to Average those Sums Rows

How is this possible?

Comment: You need PowerPivot.

Comment: I have 2016 Excel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have PowerPivot, which you should if you have 2016, and assuming a table called Table1 loaded into the data model, you can add a measure for the sum, called say `TotalNumber`, which is just:

```
=SUM(Table1[Numbers])
```

Then add another measure which is the one you'll use in the pivot table:

```
=IF(HASONEVALUE(Table1[Date]),[TotalNumber],averagex(VALUES(Table1[Date]),Table1[TotalNumber]))
```